# svn error on checkout in public ip

Tags: svn

I am facing an issue with svn.  As it is working fine on my local domain while I am also able to view it on the browser locally and remotely.  But the problem occurs when I am about to list or checkout the svn link and it gives below error.

> ```
> E:\svnco>svn list http://*:8888/svn/project/trunk/opt/sh/
> svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn/project/!svn/rvr/237/trunk/opt/sh': Could not read status line: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  (http://*:8888)
>
> svn co  http://*:8888/svn/project/trunk/opt/sh/ .
> svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn/project/!svn/rvr/236/trunk/opt/sh': Could not read status line: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (http://*:8888)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You're providing the URL that's not likely to be valid.  Based on what you've show you're using this URL: `http://*:8888`.  `*` is not likely to be a valid hostname.

However, it's possible the `*` is just your placeholder for the real hostname.  It does appear that you are at least connecting to the remote server.  It's possible that you have a proxy or something between you and the actual Subversion server that's rejecting PROPFIND requests.

Can you perhaps get the error logs from the Subversion server?